# why is ${variable} not substituted

Tags: java, jsp

I have this little piece of code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= request.getAttribute("index_title") %></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:out value="${request['index_title']}" />
</body>
</html>
```

the expression `<%= request.getAttribute("index_title") %>` is correctly substituted, but `<c:out value="${request['index_title']}" />` is not. I also tried `${request['index_title']}` and `${index_title}` but no one works.

That's my first jsp, so I really think it must be a trivial error, but I am not able to understand where the error is.

**Additional question:**

in my servlet I do `request.setAttribute ("index_title", "page title");` . Can the problem be related to the fact that what I'm adding to the request is not a bean?

Comment: Surely the problem isn't there but you are mixing namespaces at your taglib references. `http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt` should be `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt`

Comment: I think I found, the problem was that my web.xml did not include the namespace. Since I'm trying to use servlet api 3.0, I never touched it. By changing it, now all the syntaxes works. But isn's web.xml optional in servlet api 3?

Comment: from my point of view you should not declare any of the standard namespaces in your `web.xml` but them you should ensure you are using the correct namespace reference in your JSP, note that from servlet 2.5 and ahead JSTL was aligned with EL and all namespaces have been relocated to `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/...`

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.index_title}"/>
```

Comment: I get ${requestScope.index_title} as output.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<c:out value="${index_title}"/>
```

Comment: I get ${index_title} as output

Answer (score 0):

You can use just the expression language, without the jstl libraries.

Use `${index_title}` (or `${requestScope.index_title}`, not sure ) directly inside the html:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= request.getAttribute("index_title") %></title>
</head>
<body>
${index_title}
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

No, you can add anything as attribute.